# Javascript/Typescript this refers to wrong scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope, this

How can I reference the parent object variables from within a sub-object?

The 'this' within sub-object here refers to the sub-object itself. However I need to reference the parent object. How can I accomplish that?

```
export class Parent {

    load() {
          this.options = {
               this. //Problem here! this refers to options object and not
                     // parent
           }
    }
}
```

The above code is very rough. Did not mean it to be very percise.

Comment: [this works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20options%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20number%20%3D%203%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20load()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.options%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3A%20this.x%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D) fine. Maybe you can explain your problem more specifically.

Answer (score -1):

this keyword works differently than other languages.  it holds the value of the object that invokes the code. Since the options object has called it, that is the 'this' object.

```
var that = this;
```

you could put that in your parent constructor to create a reference to the parent object.

I suggest you take a look at this blog post, very helpful: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/